# VS Code: Keyboard shortcuts for switching back and forth between top and bottom panels?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm usually either editing a file or using a tab in the lower panel (I can't find the name of it, but it contains the Problems, Output, Debug Console, and Terminal tabs), and I found the shortcuts for switching to an active file or a specific bottom-panel tab, but not how to just switch to the top or bottom panels back to whatever focus they were on (similar to switching applications on Windows which keeps your cursor in its place and focuses on it so you can continue typing)...

I'm looking here but not seeing the shortcuts for these things: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Knowing how to switch panels like this would really speed things up...

Comment: Go into your vscode keyboard shortcuts from preferences and search "toggleTerminal", it should be ```Ctrl + ~``` by default. Also hovering over the buttons tells you the shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the default keyboard combination is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

[image: toggle panel]

Comment: That hides the bottom pane (Terminal for me usually) and sets cursor to where it was in editor, then reverse for me on another hit, so this is effective enough and maybe a little extra handy for getting the bottom pane out of the way of the code editor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization)

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+9",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusPanel",
    "when": "!panelFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+9",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "panelFocus"
},
```